# 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to merge one audio and one video which will come from NSFileManager. When I was trying I got an error. Then I created another project and it's completely fine. But when I try to execute this in my main project I get an error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Here's how I try to merge:

To get data from Document directory I wrote a function called `getData`.

```
func getData(){
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    do {
        // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        print(directoryContents)

        // if you want to filter the directory contents you can do like this:
        videoUrlforMarge = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mov" } as [AnyObject]
        //videoUrlforMarge.append(directoryContents[1] as AnyObject)
        print("this video \(videoUrlforMarge[0])")

        audioUrl = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "caf" } as [AnyObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Here is my merge function:

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:NSURL, audioUrl:NSURL)
{
    let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    //start merge
    let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl as URL)
    let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl as URL)

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]

    do{
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    }catch{
    }

    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

    let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)

    //        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
    //        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    //
    //
    //        AVPlayerVC.player = player

    //        let fm = FileManager.default
    //        let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    //        let savePathUrl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4")

    //find your video on this URl
    //let savePathUrl : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo.mp4")
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let  savePathUrl = NSURL(string: ("\(documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("temp"))" + ".mp4"))

    let VideoFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo\(arc4random()%1000)d")!.appendingPathExtension("mp4").absoluteString

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: VideoFilePath)
    {
        do
        {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: VideoFilePath)
        }
        catch { }
    }

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: VideoFilePath) as URL
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:
            //Uncomment this if u want to store your video in asset

            let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
            assetsLib.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: savePathUrl! as URL, completionBlock: nil)

            print("success")
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(String(describing: assetExport.error))")
        default:
            print("complete")
        }
    }
}
```

and finally I try to merge by an action and here is it.

```
@IBAction func margeTest(_ sender: Any) {
    let videoUrl  = videoUrlforMarge[0]
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl.absoluteString!!)
    let audio  = audioUrl[0]
    let urla = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audio.absoluteString!!)

    self.mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl: url , audioUrl: urla )
}
```

I was following some code in stack overflow but got this error.

Comment: On which line this error occurs?

Comment: in which line stop your app execution with the crash?

Comment: i was trying to debug by using break poin. after go to this line   let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]  app crash.

Comment: Error says that array that aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) returns is empty array

Comment: how can it it be solved ??

Comment: Solve by not reading an array element from an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your `aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)` array and `aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)` array have some value before access to position in the array by index, adding a guard can help you with this

```
guard aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).count > 0 && aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio) > 0 else{
             return
        }

let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]
```

Also Make sure that your `videoUrlforMarge` array and `audioUrl` array have some value before access to position in the array by index, using the same procedure

**replace your mergeTest action code by this one**

```
@IBAction func margeTest(_ sender: Any) {

        guard videoUrlforMarge.count > 0 && audioUrl.count > 0 else{
             return
        }

        let videoUrl  = videoUrlforMarge[0]
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoUrl.absoluteString!!)
        let audio  = audioUrl[0]
        let urla = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audio.absoluteString!!)

        self.mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl: url , audioUrl: urla )
    }
```

**My answer will don't help you with *WHY ARE YOURS ARRAYS EMPTY PROBLEM* but helps you to don't crash on this, maybe that issue is caused by your `aVideoAsset` and `aAudioAsset` urls used for initialisation**

## updated

**Try this way to get your `savePathUrl` working**

```
    let filename = "temp.mp4"
    let documentsURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!)
    let savePath = documents.appendingPathComponent(fileName).path
    let  savePathUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)
```

Comment: @FaizulKarim check again I had updated my answer again after knowing which line is crashing, please try again and let me know

Comment: Thank's Reiner melian. Error is gone. But my video is not saving in photos. But i was save videos this way

Comment: I don't know, no me, I always explain a down vote @FaizulKarim

Comment: Another help please .. assetsLib.writeVideoAtPath(toSavedPhotosAlbum: VideoFilePath, completionBlock: nil) .. This videoFilepaht is string formate According to my code. So how can i convert it url tha AssetsLib need

Comment: @FaizulKarim I had updated my answer please let me know if works for you

Comment: can you please update the ans. there is another problem.   failed Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17444cd80 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12842 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12842), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})